# forEach array getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to clean some sheets, individually i make it work uncommenting and changing sheet name

```
function doClean(sheet) 
{
// var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Resultado");

var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
var LC = sheet.getLastColumn();

sheet.getRange(1,1,LR,LC).getDisplayValues()
sheet.createTextFinder("-").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
sheet.createTextFinder("0").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
sheet.createTextFinder("0,00").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
sheet.createTextFinder("0,0000").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
};
```

but when when i try to group in array and execute with foreach

```
function doCleanSheets() {
 var sheet = ["BLC", "Balanço", "DRE", "Resultado", "FLC", "Fluxo", "DVA", "Valor"];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().sheet.forEach(doClean);
};
```

im getting error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
> doCleanSheets   @ - 10x_to_11x.gs:87

line 87 is `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().sheet.forEach(doClean);`

searched for error, but results were way more complex than my case, and i couldnt apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script, unfortunately, `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` has no property of `sheet`. By this, such error occurs. When you want to use the sheet names of `sheet` in the forEach, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `doCleanSheets` as follows.

```
function doCleanSheets() {
  var sheet = ["BLC", "Balanço", "DRE", "Resultado", "FLC", "Fluxo", "DVA", "Valor"];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(s => sheet.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  sheets.forEach(doClean);
}
```

#### References:

- [getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function doClean(sheet) {
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var LC = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, LR, LC).getDisplayValues()
  sheet.createTextFinder("-").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
  sheet.createTextFinder("0").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
  sheet.createTextFinder("0,00").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
  sheet.createTextFinder("0,0000").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith("");
};
function doCleanSheets() {
 var sheet = ["BLC", "Balanço", "DRE", "Resultado", "FLC", "Fluxo", "DVA", "Valor"];
 sheet.forEach(sh => doClean(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().geSheetByName(sh)));
};
```

Comment: got error TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActive(...).getshByName is not a function
, typo getshByName fix getSheetByName, but thanks, got to see another way to do the same thing